# How to Hide controller name and page name in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the Url i am getting like this 
http://localhost:50749/Admin/Admin/Dashboard
but i need only, http://localhost:50749

In route.config i wrote like this.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)    
{      
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { Controller="Admin",action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the default route:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)    
{      
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { Controller="Admin",action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If the default is using so write:

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)    
    {      
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { Controller="Admin",action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and the url must to be  http://localhost:50749/Admin/

Comment: hi, with default route i am getting the same out put like  http://localhost:50749/Admin/Admin/Dashboard 
but i need only, http://localhost:50749

Comment: if i make url to empty in default route then i am getting the correct output, but after that in layout page i created a menu in that if i click any page it is showing page not found.

Comment: How does the URL look?
How do you create it?

Comment: is it possible to show only single url for all clicks in the menu and data has to change according to pages?